# Compiler does not like INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I try to determine the Name (including path) of a process from its window handle:

```
function PAGetProcessNameFromWnd(Wnd: HWND): string;
var
  ThisList: TStringList;
  PID: DWORD;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Winapi.Windows.IsWindow(Wnd) then
  begin
    PID := Winapi.Windows.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    //PID := SysUtils.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    Winapi.Windows.GetWindowThreadProcessId(Wnd, @PID);
    ThisList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      if JclSysInfo.RunningProcessesList(ThisList, True) then
      begin
        I := ThisList.IndexOfObject(Pointer(PID));
        if I > -1 then
          Result := ThisList[I];
      end;
    finally
      ThisList.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When I BUILD the app I often get a compiler error at this line:

```
PID := Winapi.Windows.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

Then I deactivate this line by commenting it and activate the subsequent line by uncommenting it:

```
PID := SysUtils.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

The error is:

> [dcc64 Error]: E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds

Then after a while (randomly) the compiler complains about this line and the game restarts by deactivating this line and reactivating the previous line. This goes ad infinitum. What is wrong here?

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: I have copied your code and there is no any errors. Probably you know more than you say.

Comment: A process ID is of type `DWORD` (32-bit unsigned integer). A handle, on the other hand, is pointer-sized. Are you compiling a 64-bit target? Regardless of that, assigning an unrelated named constant (such as `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`) to a value storing an ID is a poor choice, no matter what. Just use `0` as a sentinel. `0` is not a valid process ID.

Comment: Yes, this is a 64-bit VCL Forms Application. I don't understand the rest of your statement. Could you please clarify what should be done?

Comment: Did you mean to assign `PID := 0;`?

Comment: Now, with `PID := 0;` there seems to be no more compiler error.

Comment: This is strange, `System.SysUtils.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;` is defined as `Winapi.Windows.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;`. For a 64 bit target the compiler should complain for either assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is defined as :

```
 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = THandle(-1);
```

where

```
 THandle = NativeUInt;
```

On a 64-bit platform this gives `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` a size of eight bytes. Assigning to a `DWORD` (four bytes) is problematic because the value (-1) overflows and this is known at compile time.  `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is not appropriate here because handles are the size of a native pointer whereas PIDs are always DWORDs - you want a PID, not a handle.

There are two signatures for `GetWindowThreadProcessId`:

```
function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd: HWND; lpdwProcessId: Pointer): DWORD; external minuser name 'GetWindowThreadProcessId';
function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd: HWND; var dwProcessId: DWORD): DWORD; external minuser name 'GetWindowThreadProcessId';
```

In either case, initializing the `PID` variable is not necessary.  From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) :

> lpdwProcessId
>
> Type: LPDWORD
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the process identifier. If this
>   parameter is not NULL, GetWindowThreadProcessId copies the identifier
>   of the process to the variable; otherwise, it does not.

So if you want to retrieve a PID value using this method then just pass a variable in without doing anything to it.  If not, just pass `0`.